# vanishing of spectral term in Arthur-Selberg trace formula for GL(2)?

Tags: trace-formula, adeles, nt.number-theory, langlands-conjectures

Hi,

In the Arthur-Selberg trace formula for $G = GL(2)/\mathbf Q$ (as seen for example in
Gelbart's "Lectures on the Trace Formula"), the spectral side includes terms
like:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty tr (\rho(\mu,it)(f))dt
$$
where $f$ is the test function, $\mu$ is a Hecke character, and $\rho(\mu,s)$
is the induced representation
$$
Ind_{B(\mathbf A)}^{G(\mathbf A)}\mu(a_1/a_2)|a_1/a_2|^s_{\mathbf A}
$$
where we write elements of $B(\mathbf A)$ (= the standard Borel of $G$) as having $a_1$, $a_2$ in the diagonal. This
term appears both in the hyperbolic and unipotent spectral terms.

I would like to understand under which condition this term vanishes. In particular, is 
there a condition on $f_{\mathbf R}$ (the infinite component of my test function $f$) that would imply the vanishing of this term?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Sorry, my original answer was adressing vanishing of the contribution of the continuous spectrum. You are asking for something different.*

If the $\infty$ component is a pseudo coefficient of the discrete series representations, the contribution you ask for vanish by the definition of a pseudo coefficient and the fact that
$$ tr \  Ind_B^G (\mu) (\phi)  = \prod\limits_v tr \ Ind_{B_v}^{G_v} (\mu_v) (\phi_v).$$

Another natural thing to choose is a pseudo coefficient of square-integrable reps at one or several $p$-adic places. Then as well your distribution vanishes.

The existence of pseudo-coefficients was proved by Delorme, Arthur, Kahzdan etc. I have constructed them explicitly for GL(2) in my PhD thesis, but the idea is essentially already in Hejhal's book.

Comment: My PhD thesis contains a lot of similar computations. You can find it on my homepage. Best, MP.

Comment: the whole spectral side does not vanish. It picks out those automorphic representations whose infinity component is discrete series. These correspond to holomorphic (and anti holomorphic) modular forms on a congruence subgroup. 

Comment: No, these traces vanish as well. The trace of a discrete series rep is essentially that of a principal series representations, except that you take away certain $K$-types in the $K$-expansion. The trace of a principal series representation equals an integral over the Levisubgroup after a $K$-expansion.

Comment: There is no nice analogy between conjugacy classes and irrep here:)

Comment: the discrete series trace is that of the principle series, minus the finite dimensional representation trace. It certainly does not vanish. This is how Selberg got a formula for the dimension of the space of holomorphic cusp forms. There is no need for "analogy". 

Comment: principal, not principle

Comment: Hejhal in his book on the trace formula combined distinct $K$-types to obtain the Eichler-Selberg trace formula for modular forms. Hejhal attributes this idea to Selberg. I am not familiar with Selberg's original paper, but there is no argument with support on elliptic elements in Hejhal.

Comment: I do not have access to the library right now (late in the evening here). I think in Lang's book, traces of functions like $f$ on discrete series reps are computed; the only time these traces are non-zero are on the space I described. By the Selberg trace formula (geometric side) for such functions, all terms except identity vanish. This proves in fact that discrete series multplicities  for congruence subgroups $\Gamma$ grow like the volume of $\Gamma$. I suggest you see the arguments of Speh-Rohlfs or Degeorgi-Wallach where more general things like these are proved. 

Comment: Okay, let's get technical to see what I might be overlooking. Let $D$ be the discrete series contained in the principal series $I(\mu)$, then $\phi \in C_c^\infty(G)$. Let $\phi$ be $K$-conjugation-invariant, and consider the $K$-expansion $\phi=\sum \phi_\sigma$, where $\sigma$ runs through the $K$-types. We have that $tr D(\phi) = \sum\limits_{\sigma \subset D} tr I(\mu)(\phi_\sigma)$ and
$ tr I(\mu)(\phi_\sigma)  = \int_M \phi_\sigma(m) \mu(m) d m$, right? So if $\phi$ is supported on elliptic elements, then $\phi_\sigma$ is as well and the trace vanishes, or not?

Comment: Ah, I see that there might be a problem with my last sentence:(

Answer (score 2):

The space of regular semi-simple elements in the infinite component $GL_2({\mathbb R})$ which are elliptic is an open set. If you take a compactly supported smooth function $f$ whose support in the reals lies in this open set, the contribution of your term vanishes. This is used, for example,in the article by Jacquet and Gelbart in the Corvallis volume.

Of course, this is not the only condition that ensures this. Since I am not very familiar with these questions, I think someone more "automorphic" may be able to tell you weaker conditions.